# How to delete a task document in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch-5

If I understand it correctly, all tasks will be store in a index called `.task`. In ES 6.2, after the task is finished, I am able to do `DELETE http://localhost:9200/.tasks/task/ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A:9637` to remove task document `ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A:9637` from `.task` index.

However, when running ES 5.5, calling the same API always gives me `"result": "not_found"`.

I also tried to check `.task` index/file directly by calling `GET http://localhost:9200/.tasks/task/ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A:9637`, this gives me `index_not_found_exception`.

How to delete a task document in ES 5.5? Or how to access a system index in ES any-version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

So, I am actually able to delete a task both in ES 5.5 and ES 6.2 using

```
DELETE http://localhost:9200/.tasks/task/ZKUuxQZpRCCcJ0njBM1P0A:9637
```

The reason I failed to delete some tasks, is that those tasks came from other server's requests with `wait_for_complete == true`. From my understanding, a `wait_for_complete == true` task is an "in-memory" only task. If such a task is canceled/completed, it is gone.

The tasks that will be stored in `.task` system index, are the tasks with `wait_for_complete == false`.